# How can I add default preview for files in Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-extension, preview-pane

If I click on a `.ts` (typescript) file and activate the Preview Pane in Windows Explorer, then I see a preview of the file:

[image]

Why? Because I set Notepad to open `.ts` files.

But I have `.js` files which I set `Notepad++` to open them and I don't see a preview in the Preview Pane:

[image]

**Question**

How can I show `.js` files in the Preview Pane and still keep Notepad++ as this file type's default program?

I don't want to open Notepad++ with the option: Right-click > Open With.

I have Windows 7.

Comment: You can try http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/previewconfig-tool-registers-file-types-for-the-preview-pane-in-windows-vista/

Comment: @Rahul2001doesn't work also. I've found out that if there is a program registered to that extension , the preview doesn't work.

Answer (score 14):

Follow these directions to edit the Registry and assign the Windows Text Preview Handler to the `.js` file extension. *(Based on this [How To Geek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/make-windows-vista-explorer-preview-pane-work-for-more-file-types/).)*

1. Open Registry Editor
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js` and make note of the content of the **(Default)** value. This is the *ProgID* to which the `.js` extension is registered:
   [image]
3. Navigate to the ProgID's key. We'll find our key at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\JSFile`
4. Expand the key. If necessary, create a subkey named *ShellEx*
5. Under the *ShellEx* key, create a new key named **{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}**.
   **Note:** According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144144(v=vs.85).aspx) the presence of this exact value tells Windows that this is a preview handler.
6. Select this newly created key and set its *(Default)* value to **{1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22}**. This is the ID for Windows' Text Preview Handler.
   [image]
7. The change will take effect immediately.

Comment: [It doesn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsK8y.png) And I even restarted `explorer.exe` (windows 7 pro)

Comment: @Royi Interesting. I tested this and it worked. Can you try these steps on another file type and see if the problem is isolated to `.js` files on your machine?

Comment: I've found out that if there is a program registered to that extension , the preview thing doesn't work.

Comment: @Royi Perhaps it matters what program is registered. In my testing I used an extension that was associated with a program that doesn't have its own preview handler.

Comment: Yeah but my question was _"and still keep Notepad++ as this file type's default program"_ ...... :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, I believe the issue is that you shouldn't be writing to keys in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. That is a synthetic **merged** view of HKLM\Software\Classes and HKCU\Software\Classes. If a program registers via HKCU (which generally it should), then anything you've written to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is shadowed. So replace "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" in these examples with "HKLM\Software\Classes". Then the under-the-hood merge succeeds and the preview thing will work.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984433/hkey-local-machine-software-classes-vs-hkey-classes-root
) sheds some light on when the merge may or may not work. The easiest thing is to avoid writing directly to "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT".

Answer (score 10):

Since the file contents are just plain text, you can make Explorer treat it as such. You can use `Content Type` and `PerceivedType` to achieve that. Here is how to do it:

1. In the Registry Editor, navigate to the key related to that file type. For the file type asked, the path would be like `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js`.
2. In that key, right-click the right panel and choose `New > String Value`.
3. Name it as `Content Type`.
4. Double click that value and set it as `text/plain`.
5. Right-click the right panel and choose `New > String Value`.
6. Name it as `PerceivedType`.
7. Double click that value and set it as `text`.

Restart Explorer and *voilá*! The file will still be associated with any editor you have set but the built-in preview feature will treat it as a text file and then show a preview.

As a side effect, if you sort/group your list in Explorer as *Perceived Type* it will be classified under *Text* file.

*Note: for instance I did a test by making a `.dummy` and associated it with Google Chrome, the file could be previewed in the Preview Pane and double-clicking it still executed Chrome as intended.*

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on Windows 10 but my system needed only Shadow suggestion:
Find the pertinent file extension, in my case I wanted .js, .txt, .java, .properties, .fewothers to be simply pre-viewed as txt files.
Then add the "PerceivedType" ==> text